# sed conditionally + append to end of line if condition applied

Tags: sed, append, eol

Playing with makefile and bash shell scripting where I ended-up having a variable containing:

```
--global-option=build_ext --global-option=--b2-args=libtorrent-python-pic=on --global-option=--b2-args=address-model=32
```

I need to convert it so double-quotes gets appended at the right place such as:

```
--global-option=build_ext --global-option=--b2-args="libtorrent-python-pic=on"  --global-option=--b2-args="address-model=32"
```

I tried the following without success:

```
echo $myvar | sed -e 's/ /\n/' | sed -z '{s/=/="/2;t;s/$/"/}'
--global-option=build_ext
--global-option="--b2-args=libtorrent-python-pic=on
```

EDIT: Note that this time it's `--b2-args=` but this could be a conjunction of `--anything=`, and the reason why I was focussing on the second instance of `=` to change for `="` and if true append `=` at the end of word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question doesn't discuss anything about prepending `--global-option=` if it's missing as in the final `--b2-args...` string on the provided input line, I think your input was really supposed to be:

```
$ cat file
--global-option=build_ext --global-option=--b2-args=libtorrent-python-pic=on --global-option=--b2-args=address-model=32
```

in which case using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's/\([^ =]*=[^= ]*=\)\([^ ]*\)/\1"\2"/g' file
--global-option=build_ext --global-option=--b2-args="libtorrent-python-pic=on" --global-option=--b2-args="address-model=32"
```

Comment: Solution works like a charm.  And as you mention it, and revisiting my code, it could make things a lot simpler if it was also prepending `--global-option=`

Comment: Ask a new question if you;d like help with that part too but obviously that's a simpler (but separate) problem.

Comment: done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71727287/sed-prepend-and-add-double-quote-conditionnally