# sed prepend and add double-quote conditionnally

Tags: sed, append, double-quotes, prepend

Playing with makefile and bash shell scripting where I ended-up having a variable containing:

```
build_ext --b2-args=libtorrent-python-pic=on --b2-args=address-model=32
```

I need to prepend `--global-option=` and append double-quotes at the right place such as:

```
--global-option=build_ext --global-option=--b2-args="libtorrent-python-pic=on"  --global-option=--b2-args="address-model=32"
```

Note that `--b2-args=` varies and cannot be taken as granted.

So far what I did for the prepending is using a bash array:

```
printf "\x2D\x2Dglobal-option=%s " "${myarray[@]}"
```

But I'd rather have a one-liner using `sed` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/=\([^ ]*\)/="\1"/g; s/[^ ]*/--global-option=&/g' file
--global-option=build_ext --global-option=--b2-args="libtorrent-python-pic=on" --global-option=--b2-args="address-model=32"
```